Working with CORS restrictions in WKWebView
I have an app that displays content in a WKWebView. We have full control over the content, which is stored in a file on the device. The app loads the content using WKWebView.loadFileURL(_:allowingReadAccessTo:).
We now need to add a new feature that injects extra content using a XMLHttpRequest() to a third-party server that requires an Authorization header. I noticed that the web view first sends a OPTIONS request to the URL with a couple of extra Access-Control-* headers. The server is responding to that request with a 401, probably because their routing doesn't differentiate between the two methods.
My understanding is that the server could respond to the OPTIONS request by returning some access control headers that tell the web view that it's OK to send an Authorization header to that server.
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization

My first question is whether this is correct, or if I'm barking up the wrong tree? If I am correct, I could set the ball rolling on getting the server people to add that support.
My second question is whether I even need to do this. If there was a way that I could tell the WKWebView about "safe" domains for file:// URLs, then I wouldn't even need to change the server. I've been unable to find anything that suggests that I can do this.
Thanks for any help or suggestions.
